# Sharing Session Cookies With Internal Domains

Tags: apache, session

Say I have two machines in my internal network running apache:

- web1.mydomain.local
- web2.mydomain.local

Is it possible to share a session cookie between them so logging into an application on web1 and clicking a link to web2 will pass the session cookie over to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following within your web.config - this should create your cookie with a ".mydomain.local" domain, accessible from both sub-domains.

```
<system.web>
<httpCookies domain=".mydomain.local" httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
</system.web>
```

I believe this should work, but if not, you will have to some amount of session cookie alteration or session management in your code-behind.